# How to include chromedriver with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, windows, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller

I am using pyinstaller to create an executable of my python script.
In the script I'm using these imports:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
etc...
```

The problem is, when running `pyinstaller myscript.py` , it will result in including Firefox, instead of Chrome. In the result folder c:...\dist\myscript\selenium\webdriver there is a firefox folder, so it is simply skipping chromedriver, and it is a serious problem for me, because the script needs to run with Chrome.
There is only a few questions around this topic, but there is no answer to solve the issue.
I was thinking on adding the `--hidden-import MODULENAME` tag to the command, but chromedriver.exe is not a module...
Thanks

Comment: You could add is as a [data file](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle), but I am not sure that it will solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out. In the meantime, I found a workaround, that is, installing chromedriver on the target machine, and adding its folder to the Path, but I must find something without it.

Comment: Why not adding your idea as an answer? :) It solved my problem, I added chromedriver.exe as a binary file to the spec. Thanks again!

Comment: @Repiklis sorry I forgot to mention you...

Comment: I am glad it worked. You found the solution. I just gave you a hint.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It should be added as a binary file, since it is a binary file...
So a custom spec file needed where the chromedriver's path on the local system and the desired location relative to the dist\myscript should be defined, so it looks something like this:

```
.....
a = Analysis(['myscript.py'],
             pathex=['path\\to\\my\\script'],
             binaries=[ ('path\\to\\my\\chromedriver.exe', '.\\selenium\\webdriver') ],
             datas=None,
....
```

And then run the pyinstaller with this spec file: `pyinstaller myscript.spec myscript.py`

Comment: I have a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41009492/pyinstaller-generated-app-does-not-link-to-the-specified-binary-chromedriver) regarding your answer

Comment: Here is an updated [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030257/is-there-a-way-to-bundle-a-binary-file-such-as-chromedriver-with-a-single-file)

Comment: Here is pyinstaller example explained in details. https://hackernoon.com/the-one-stop-guide-to-easy-cross-platform-python-freezing-part-1-c53e66556a0a. And here how packaging works https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/everything.html

Comment: How about firefox webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and solved it by adding the following code into my Spec file.

These paths are for windows OS:

```
a = Analysis(
    ['myproject.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[('C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe','Drivers')],
    datas=None,
)
```

and then pressed `Shift` + `right click` on my project folder to open PowerShell window.

Then use this:

```
pyinstaller  myproject.spec   myproject.py
```