# Is there a way to bundle a binary file (such as chromedriver) with a single file app/exe compiled with Pyinstaller?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller

As noted in the answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41009492/pyinstaller-generated-app-does-not-link-to-the-specified-binary-chromedriver/41010734#41010734), setting the path to chromedriver in `binaries` in the Pyinstaller spec file (`binaries=[('/usr/bin/chromedriver', './selenium/webdriver')]`) didn’t have an effect (unless it was set incorrectly). That is, chromedriver is accessed as long as it’s in the PATH (/usr/bin in this case). My question regards the possibility to bundle chromedriver in the background so that it doesn’t have to be manually installed on another machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I succesfully bundled chromedriver with pyinstaller (although unfortunately, my virusscanner flagged it, after I ran the exe, but that's another problem)

I guess your problem is that you do not give the correct path to the webdriver in the script (using keyword executable_path). Also, I included the chromedriver as a data-file, although I'm not sure if that makes a difference..

Here is my example.

sel_ex.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver

import os, sys, inspect     # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path
current_folder = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(os.path.split(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe() ))[0]))

def init_driver():
    chromedriver = os.path.join(current_folder,"chromedriver.exe")
    # via this way, you explicitly let Chrome know where to find 
    # the webdriver.
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = chromedriver) 
    return driver

if __name__ == "__main__":
    driver = init_driver()
    driver.get("http://www.imdb.com/")
```

sel_ex.spec:

```
....
binaries=[],
datas=[("chromedriver.exe",".")],
....
```

In this way, the chromedriver was stored in the main folder, although it should not matter where it is stored, as long as the script correct path through the keyword executable_path

disclaimers:
-I did not use the one-file-settings, but that shouldn't make a difference.
-my OS is windows

Comment: Just to clarify and consolidate relevant posts, I believe this problem was solved in a post I formatted differently here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41009492/pyinstaller-generated-app-does-not-link-to-the-specified-binary-chromedriver. The last comment I made to the person who posted the answer specifies why.

Comment: So yes, the path was the reason