# How to include chromedriver executable in Pyinstaller so that it works for computers that do not have chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller

I created an executable using Pyinstaller, and my application uses chromedriver and selenium. I followed what was mentioned in [Running pyinstaller another pc with Chromedriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47690548/running-pyinstaller-another-pc-with-chromedriver), I used the following command.

```
pyinstaller --onefile -i "icon.ico" --add-binary "pathToChromedriver.exe";"." script.py
```

It works on my computer and for other computers that have chromedriver installed, but for those that do not, it gives me an error saying that the chromedriver version must be greater than some version.
How can I fix this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't recommend to do as that. Chromedriver is compatible with Chrome browser, so one chromedriver can't support vary version Chrome on client.  A better way is to implement get client browser version, then get compatible chromedriver from https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads, then download & install it on client.

Comment: How would I get the client browser version?

Comment: You can pass the chrome version in pyinstall cmd line if it's no easy to get it by script.