# Python - Pyinstaller - Import selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pyinstaller

I tried to compile a python file from PyCharm and got different errors in the warning.txt file.

This are my imports I use in my File:

```
from selenium import common
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

This is the error in "build/filename/filename.txt

```
missing module named 'selenium.webdriver' - imported by C:\Users\Raphael\PycharmProjects\InstaBot\InstaBot_2_0.py (top-level)
missing module named selenium - imported by C:\Users\Raphael\PycharmProjects\InstaBot\InstaBot_2_0.py (top-level)
```

How can i solve that?
I put the chrome- and geckodriver.exe in the folder, where the FILENAME.exe was.

I tried different approaches:

- hidden import selenium
- add selenium as binary
- took the --onefile flag and still get the Error

I found and tried this posts:

[No module named when using PyInstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733467/no-module-named-when-using-pyinstaller)

[How to include chromedriver with pyinstaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39563851/how-to-include-chromedriver-with-pyinstaller)

[PyInstaller, spec file, ImportError: No module named 'blah'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436132/pyinstaller-spec-file-importerror-no-module-named-blah)

Thanks for reading this and have a nice day!

I use:

- PyCharm: 2020.1
- Python 3.7, Anaconda
- Chromedriver 81.0.4044.69
- PyInstaller: 3.6
- Selenium: 3.141.0

Comment: I had a similar issue with PyQt imports which I had installed with `conda`. But when I installed it with `pip` I did not have the issue anymore. Consider, installing selenium using `pip install selenium`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to  Vikramaditya Gaonkar !!!

It actual worked by reinstalling pyinstaller and selenium with `pip install selenium` and `pip install pyinstaller`!

Thank you!