# Is it possible to include third party app.exe file inside pyinstaller standalone executable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dependencies, exe, pyinstaller

I have a simple `my_script.py` for batch file processing. But it has dependency from third party windows executable `app.exe` file.
So, the question: is it possible to include `app.exe` inside standalone `my_script.exe` generated with pyinstaller?
Another solution, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this one:

[How to include chromedriver with pyinstaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39563851/how-to-include-chromedriver-with-pyinstaller)

It worked for me and should also work for other .exe